# Ant check if a directory (and sub directories) contains a certain file

Tags: ant

I'm trying to check in Ant if a directory (and sub directories) contains a certain file

I'm using ant contrib with :

```
<if>
  <available>
    <filepath>
      <fileset dir="myDir">
        <include name="**/*.AEF" />
      </fileset>
    </filepath>
  </available>
<then>
  <fail/>
</then>
</if>
```

I want to fail if there is at least a file ending with "AEF" in myDir or one of its sub-directories.
But this fails even if no "*.AEF" file is found

Answer (score 7):

This should do the job, without the need of ant-contrib:

```
<fail message="At least one .AEF file was found">
  <condition>
    <resourcecount when="greater" count="0">
      <fileset dir="myDir" includes="**/*.AEF" />
    </resourcecount>
  </condition>
</fail>
```